# jQuery grab input value in table loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
var table = $("#b-table");
table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),    
    qLine       = $tds.eq(0).text(),
    qPartNumber = $tds.eq(1).text(),
    qComments   = $tds.eq(5).val();

    console.log(qLine);
    console.log(qPartNumber);
    console.log(qComments);

  });
```

qLine and qPartNumber are copying over fine, as these are text values within the `td` element, but qComments is not copying over, as within the `td` element is another `input` element, like so:

```
<td><input class="qComments" type="text"></td>
```

I've tried using:

```
$tds.eq(5).val();
$tds.eq(5).html();
$tds.eq(5).text();
$tds.input.eq(5).val();
$tds.eq(5).input.val();
```

and none of these capture the value of the input - and the last two error out for bad syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$tds.eq(5).find("input").val();
```

Comment: perfect - I should have thought of using find a second time.  Thanks!